# puzzled about one parameter matrix flows describing geodesic flow and horocyclic flow

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm referencing material from: [Dynamics of geodesic and horocyclic flows](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/barbara.schapira/recherche/texteCIRM-Hasselblatt.pdf) and [Hyperbolic coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_coordinates).

The upper half plane can be given a hyperbolic structure and since there is a bijection to the first quadrant using hyperbolic coordinates, horocycles in the upper half plane can be corresponded to hyperbola in the first quadrant. So from what I understand the horocyclic flow transforms points and moves them along horocycles, which I will correspond to hyperbolas in the first quadrant.

> Why then is the one parameter matrix flow of the horocyclic flow given by:

$$\bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & s \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},s\in\Bbb R\bigg\}?$$

It would seem to me that the horocylic flow should be given by:

$$\bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}
e^{t/2} & 0 \\
0 & e^{-t/2}
\end{pmatrix},t\in\Bbb R\bigg\}.$$

Because this matrix "moves" points along a hyperbola.

But the author in the first link states this second matrix is the one parameter matrix flow of the *geodesic flow.*

Comment: It is better to simply apply to $z$ which gives $z+s$. This flow travels along a circle tangent at infinity. To obtain the circles tangent at the real line you need to act on the right. For details on why these are horocycles have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horocycle

Comment: You might have misunderstood this quote on the article you linked: "Since hyperbolas in Q [the first quadrant] correspond to lines parallel to the boundary of HP [the hyperbolic plane], they are horocycles in the metric geometry of Q". What this says is that in Q, every hyperbola is a horocycle. It does *not* say that in Q, every horocycle is a hyperbola. In HP there are many more horocycles than horizontal lines, namely circles tangent to the real line, and these transfer under a change of coordinates to curves in Q not described in that article.

Comment: @LeeMosher can you tell me where to look to find what these other horocycles look like in Q?

Comment: I don't know of any literature about the first quadrant $Q$ as a model of hyperbolic geometry. I can only suggest that you write down the bijection from the upper half plane $\mathbb H$ to the first quadrant $Q$, write down the formula for horocycles in $\mathbb H$, and use the bijection to transform the formula from $\mathbb H$ to $Q$.